# No connection made to MS SQL via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL database through PHP, but the connection doesn't seem to be ever made or it times out, not sure. When I load the file via localhost, I get the `check1` debug statement but not `check2`. What am I missing? I can connect and navigate the database via MS Server Management Studio.

My environment

```
PHP Version 5.2.6
Window 7 64-bit
```

In my `php.ini` file, I added the following and verified those drivers are in the proper `extension_dir`.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

Code below:

```
<?php
print_r("check1");
$serverName = "servername\instance"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"user.name", "PWD"=>"abc$1s");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

print_r("check2");

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

edit:
Tried again after installing version 3 PHP SQL drivers and with PHP version 5.4.32 with no luck.

Comment: You have an unreachable statement in your code. `or die` when setting up `$conn` means `$conn` will never be falsy, so the `else` will never execute.

Comment: Remove `or die("cannot connect to server");` - it is redundant because you're already checking if the variable holds true. If it's false it dies anyways.

Comment: Thanks for that. After removing the `die` statement, I still do not get the later debug statements.

Comment: Is your sqlsrv version 2.0? It seems like 3 and that driver doesn't support php 5.2. check this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver)

Comment: It is not. I only saw version 3 available in the download section so that's what I installed. I'll search for v2 and retry again. Thanks!

Comment: No luck with version 2.0 drivers. I'm guessing the next step is to install a higher version of PHP?